# ActiveMQ over SSL: "acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true" not working

Tags: ssl, jms, ssl-certificate, activemq-classic

I had posted a different question and now I'm editing it because I managed to do what I was achieving at first. Using "[How do I use SSL](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html)" I set up my ActiveMQ Broker accepting SSL connections and I was trying to implement a client to test the communication. I figured out that I could do this by setting the system properties:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/amq/SSL/client.ks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/amq/SSL/client.ts");
}
```

The problems I was having were in the creation of the keystores/truststores and exporting the broker certificate. When I deleted the .ks and .ts files and re-did everything as explained in "[How do I use SSL](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html)" it worked.

**My new question is:** How can I establish a connection without the need of creating a keystore for the client and importing the broker's certificate?

I am looking for a way to accept any certificate that the broker sends me. In [this link](http://timbish.blogspot.com.br/2010/04/ussing-ssl-in-nmsactivemq.html) I found a way setting an URI option:

```
ssl://localhost:61617?transport.acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true
```

but it's not working for me. From the moment I append "?transport.acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true" in my URI or URL string the method stops working, and I no longer can establish a connection.

Can anyone provide me with an example of a java or c++ client that connects to an ActiveMQ broker using SSL without importing the broker's certificate, or in other words, accepting any invalid certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI flag you are referencing is only valid for .NET clients using NMS.ActiveMQ the C++ and Java clients don't have this setting.  There is a way in the C++ client to do this, you must set a system property as follows before creating the Connection.

```
System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.disablePeerVerification", "true" );
```

The easiest way to get the ssl certs working without these testing options is to create a root certificate and then create the broker cert with you root certificate and add the root certificate to the client's trust store that way any broker with a cert signed by your root cert will be trusted.

Comment: Worked with my [ActiveMQ-CPP](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/) example. Now I will look for a similar property for my java client.

Comment: I know this is a decade late, but just to potentially save someone some confusion:  Tim *meant* to type:
System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.disablePeerVerification", "false" );
[notice "set" vs. "get"]

Comment: Oops.  I missed another one.  Tim also *meant* to make that second parameter "true" instead of "false":
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
decaf::lang::System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.disablePeerVerification", "true" );